# Collect all pull requests after the latest release on github

Tags: git, github

In my project, I always put issues that are handled in the release as follows.

```
#100 feature A
#101 Some fix
#102 feature B
#105 feature E
```

However, as the # of branches increases, it gets harder to manually chase all PRs that are merged after the latest releases.
Is there any easy way to show list of the merged branches ordered by merge date descending?
(Hopefully filter out the merges older than the latest version tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer command line utilities, you can use `git log` options to see what matches your requirements.

```
git log --pretty="%h - %s" --after="2008-10-01"
```

Or you can use what was checked in for the last 2 weeks.

```
git log --since=2.weeks
```

Here, you can find more options:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History

Comment: Thank you! The commands also show information other than merges, but simply adding `--grep 'Merge pull request'` did what I exactly wanted.

Comment: @sora That only captures PRs merged via the GitHub UI that keep the default merge commit title. You can still change the commit title when mergeing on GitHub. Or, you can merge PRs via plain `git merge`, which defaults to `Merge branch 'source-branch-name'`.